# Telnetd not working ubuntu server 23.10

Tags: apt, server, telnet, inetd

I am trying to set up telnet server in my ubuntu server 23.10 machine. I am able to install telnetd service and gives me no error but when i try to see if its running using netstat -ltp and there is no port listening for telnet. When I run sudo systemctl status telnetd it says unit telnetd.service could not be found. Any advise on this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzv2j.png)

Comment: You can get a list of files provided by the `telnetd` package with `dpkg -L telnetd`.

Comment: Why on *earth* do you attempt to configure telnetd? We're in 2024, telnet has been dead for at least 15 years. Use ssh.